# Why am I getting this Import Error? ImportError: cannot import name 'setting' from 'social_django.utils'

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am not completely sure what all info is needed to diagnose this issue so I want to apologize in advance.  I am trying to allow people to login via facebook and when I tried to migrate my changes I received this Import Error. ImportError: cannot import name 'setting' from 'social_django.utils'

Answer (score 0):

I think you should import psa like from social_django.utils import psa
in your get_user_login/views.py file The package has been updated to change the package structure since the answer posted. Kindly check the updated documentation here http://python-social-auth-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use_cases.html#signup-by-oauth-access-token

Comment: you just copy-paste from other answers

Comment: I added from social_django.utils import psa into my views.py folder but this did not resolve my issue.  If there is more information that is needed to diagnose this issue please let me know and I will post whatever is necessary.